# Confusion of "Lead"

Tags: betting-strategy, raise

I'm a new player. I confuse about the "lead" concept.

For example, at pre-flop, in the case 1, player A open raised $10, player B called. Player A is leader.

But in the case 2, player A open raised $10, player B re-raised $30 and player A called. Who is the leader?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, references to a lead bet are consistent with the definition at [pokerdictionary](http://www.pokerdictionary.net/glossary/lead/):

> The player who makes the first bet in any given betting
>   round. This bet is always made on post-flop streets and when playing
>   out of position (OOP).
>
> EXAMPLE “I check called the flop and lead the turn with TPTK, since it
>   was possible the cbettor would check back the turn with a marginal
>   holding.”

Although maybe there's exceptions in some circles, I'm not used to the terminology being used as a noun (leader) but just as a verb.  Calling somebody the leader could create some confusion in a tournament where a chip leader is a totally different thing.  Also, using the definition as above, "leader" wouldn't hold much value as a descriptor because it doesn't carry over from street to street--on any new street any person can "lead the betting" when given the opportunity.

In both of your examples then, neither player would be the "leader" since it is preflop.  Player A could "lead" the flop by betting in either case, but nothing player B does would be something we'd call a lead because they are in position.

Answer (score 0):

The leader is the player who performed the most recent aggressive move (bet or raise).

In case 2 player B is the leader.